# Problems with Ruby/Gosu relative file referencing

Tags: ruby, libgosu

So I'm making a game with Ruby/Gosu and the lines to load all the images look like this:

`@image_name = Gosu::Image.new(self, 'C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\gamefolder\assets\bg.jpg', false)`

I want to refer to them based on their location relative to the referring file. The file which includes the above line is in `C:\Users\Carlos\Desktop\gamefolder\`, so I would think I could just change the above to `'\assets\bg.jpg'` or `'assets\bg.jpg'`, but this doesn't work.

The specific error is "`Could not load image assets/bg.jpg using either GDI+ or FreeImage: Unknown Error (Runtime Error).`"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the current directory (of your execution context, not necessarily the file you're 'in'), just use `Dir.pwd`. Output this to console to check that your current directory is actually `gamefolder`.

To get the current directory of your actual ruby file (relative to `Dir.pwd`), use `__FILE__`, e.g.

```
File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

Pass that to `File.expand_path` to get a fully-qualified path. You can do a little sanity check by making sure `File.exists?("#{File.expand_path File.dirname __FILE__}/assets/bg.jpg")` returns true.

(Try `File.expand_path('assets/bg.jpg')`...that might be all you need here.)

Comment: I tried using `File.expand_path()`, and it did work, but now the game is running very slowly, and heating my computer up like mad. Any idea why this would be? Also, what do you mean "use `Dir.pwd`? Use it where?

Comment: You would use `Dir.pwd` to get the current directory, that's all I meant. If `File.expand_path` is working for you then use that. (I'm going to guess the heat and slowness is the result of some immense image processing effort! Are the images appropriately small, and are you sure you aren't reading them inside a loop?)

Comment: The only time they're read is in the `initialize` method of the game window object. All I did was change the explicit reference to the file to `File.expand_path('assets/file.jpg')`, and the game seemed to run about half speed.

Comment: That's bizarre. Try talking this change out (and just this change) as it shouldn't make one iota of difference. (Unless it's suddenly reading the images up properly for the first time...but I'm sure you'd have noticed that.)